# Sliding Panel Open click

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

```css
.destination {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130vh;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.destination-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 0px 0 0;
}

.destination-inner h1 {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 29px;
    color: #555555;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

.destination-inner h1 span {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.destination-inner h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.destination-inner h3 {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding-top: 80px;
}

.destination-inner p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.destination-inner hr {
    width: 14%;
    color: #fe0103;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.destination-inner ul {
    max-width:90%;  
    padding: 0px 30px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
}

.destination-inner li {
    background-color: #32374a;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 320px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    padding: 70px 40px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    list-style: none;
}

.destination-inner li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.destination-inner li:hover {
    background-color: #393F55;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<section class="destination" id="travels">
         <div class="destination-inner">
              <h2>STEP 01</h2>
              
              <h1>Choose your <span>Destination</span></h1>
              <hr>
             <p>They are innovative and carefully researched and curated.<br> They guides are also hand picked, and are highly experienced, very often with a special expertise.<br> The vehicles are able to be adapted to more active days of touring.</p>
              <ul data-grid="Grid 3">
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">    
                      <h3>City & <br>Table Mountain</h3>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">    
                      <h3>The Cape <br>Peninsula</h3>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">    
                      <h3>The <br>Winelands</h3>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">    
                      <h3>The <br>Overberg</h3>
                      </a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
    </section>
```

I trust we are all good. I am trying to create a content sliding effect for the section of blocks(refer to img attached).

Is it possible to create something where, when a user clicks on any block out of the 4, a new section of 4 blocks slides in to replace the current block?

I'm still a baby when it comes to JavaScript and I have been looking for tuts but no luck. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Main Block]

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to achieve a wizard kind of feature here, like from step 1 to step 2 to step 3 and so on and show some results in the end. You may also want to go back and forth with these steps.

jQuery Smart Wizard - http://techlaboratory.net/jquery-smartwizard is all you need.

You can easily customize this plugin as per your need. For example, you can go the next step when user clicks on any of the four cards. All you have to do is to simply write this:

> $('#smartwizard').smartWizard("next");

You can write this code when we click on any of the four cards. So you can provide same class names to all four cards and use above code on clicking.

For example:

> $(".card").click(function() { $('#smartwizard').smartWizard("next"); });

This plugin will surely help you and will take most of the overhead, like going back one step and making changes.

If you need any help with the implementation, please reach out, however, the site has super helpful documentation.

Please note that there are plenty of other plugins also and we can also write this code on our own, but I really like this one.

**Specifics**: The animation you wanted to achieve here, like clicking on one card will bring 4 new cards will happen with ease here.

You just have to write the HTML as mentioned on the plugin site.

Best,
Sumit